# EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW Unreal Engine 5.1

Tags: widget, stack-overflow, unreal-engine5

Made a simple clicker on widgets. I saved the project, made an archive, after I go into the project, but it crashes with an error

```
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW

UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!<lambda_e2fcebb0769fb73f1f7185c23a2b6a0e>::operator()() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3221]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3429]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2953]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3457]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2953]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4661]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3779]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3956]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1682]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!<lambda_e2fcebb0769fb73f1f7185c23a2b6a0e>::operator()() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3301]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3429]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2953]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3457]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2953]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:4661]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::CreateExportAndPreload() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3779]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::LoadAllObjects() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3956]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!LoadPackageInternal() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\UObjectGlobals.cpp:1682]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!<lambda_e2fcebb0769fb73f1f7185c23a2b6a0e>::operator()() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3301]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3429]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2953]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImportInner() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:3457]
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject!FLinkerLoad::VerifyImport() [D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\LinkerLoad.cpp:2953]
```

I don't understand what could be the problem